# Why does StrongSwan charon-cmd client require the --cert command-line option for multiple CA chain certificates?

Tags: vpn, strongswan

I have a StrongSwan charon server on Ubuntu 18.04.  I connect to this server with a StrongSwan charon-cmd client from another Ubuntu Linux machine.

The command I use from the client machine to connect to the server is:

`charon-cmd --cert ./GoDaddyCA1.crt --cert GoDaddyCA2.crt --host xxx.example.com --identity myusername`

It works great, but I don't understand why I need two "--cert" options in the command line to trust both GoDaddy CA certificates in the chain.

My personal certificate is served by the StrongSwan server, and its authority is the GoDaddyCA1.crt.  The GoDaddyCA1.crt certificate has an authority of the GoDaddyCA2.crt certificate.  The GoDaddyCA2.crt is a self-signed root certificate.

So, the authority chain is:

`MyPersonalCert.crt -> GoDaddyCA1.crt -> GoDaddyCA2.crt`

The meaning of the charon-cmd command-line option "--cert" is to declare that "this is a certificate that I trust".  So, I would expect that by trusting the GoDaddyCA1.crt, then my personal certificate should also be trusted.

But that's not good enough for charon-cmd.  The charon-cmd client demands that I specify "--cert" to trust all the way to a self-signed certificate.  But this seems superfluous.  If I trust the intermediate CA certificate, then obviously I must also trust it's authority CA cert, right?

Is this a bug, or a feature?  If it's a feature, what benefit does it provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intermediate CA certificates are currently not accepted as trust anchor in strongSwan, only self-signed root CA certificates.

If the server sends the intermediate CA certificate along with the server certificate, you only have to trust the root CA certificate (i.e. `--cert GoDaddyCA2.crt` will be enough). If it doesn't, make sure it's installed and check the config (e.g. `send_cert` in [swanctl.conf](https://docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/swanctl/swanctlConf.html)). Only if that's not an option, you can't avoid having to configure both certificates on the client.

Comment: Thank you for this advice.  I do not have an /etc/swanctl directory in my Linux distribution (Ubuntu 18.04), and therefore I don't have a swanctl.conf file (or I don't know where it is).  I have StrongSwan 5.6.2 from a few years ago, so maybe this is a new config file?   Is there some configuration in 5.6.2 that is analogous, which will allow me to configure the server to send an intermediate CA certificate?

Comment: Did you check if it's already sent? Otherwise, check the _leftsendcert_ setting in ipsec.conf and make sure the intermediate CA certificate is installed in `/etc/ipsec.d/cacerts`.

Comment: You were right, once I added the intermediate cert to the /etc/ipsec.d/cacerts directory, then it automatically sent it.  So there was nothing to configure, and it works now without the client needing to trust multiple certs.  Thanks!